# Forloops trouble jekyll

Tags: html, for-loop, jekyll

I am trying to add a heading and a description to my galleries in the page **galerie.html** that are for looped but am having an issue with this, the link to the entire website: https://github.com/smarchitects/smarchitectsweb

How do I add a headline and description into the for loop?
Thank you!

I tried adding this code snippet:

```
<div class="col-12 center">
<h2>{{item.headline}}</h2>
<p>{{item.about}}</p>
</div>
```

in various places in the for loop and loop and then added this in various places in the front data:

"- headline: XXX"
"- about: YYY"

but none of the combinations worked for me...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the loop code and the gallery data in your post. Most probably a similar issue like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74433817/how-to-define-jekyll-frontmatter-with-a-nested-list/74496569#74496569

Answer (score 0):

Nice website! I cannot reproduce the issue and see any problem because your code is working for me.

Using `{{ section | inspect }}` shows this on the page:

`{"gallery"=>[{"column-size"=>"col-4_sm-12", "aspect-ratio"=>"landscape", "background_image"=>"/images/1.jpg", "description"=>"Karolína Harrachov"}, {"column-size"=>"col-4_sm-12", "aspect-ratio"=>"landscape", "background_image"=>"/images/2022Harrachovexterier/SMARCH_HARR_03_FINAL_.jpg", "description"=>"Karolína Harrachov"}, {"column-size"=>"col-4_sm-12", "aspect-ratio"=>"landscape", "background_image"=>"/images/2022Harrachovexterier/SMARCH_HARR_02B_FINAL_CORR01_.jpg", "description"=>"Karolína Harrachov"}]}`

Your current code (below) seems to work fine though:

```
{%for section in page.galleries%}
 
<section class="padded">
    <div class="capped-width m-l-center m-r-center" id="projekt-{{forloop.index}}">
      
      <div class="gallery grid" id="lightgallery-{{forloop.index}}">
        {% for item in section.gallery %}
      
          <a class="{{item.column-size}} gallery-item" href="{{item.background_image}}">
            <div class="bg-image lazy-div relative {{item.aspect-ratio}}" data-main="{{item.background_image}}">
                <div class="galerie-overlay">
                  {{ item.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </a> 
      
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
  </div>
  </section>
{%endfor%}
```

The description text is shown as expected as an overlay when hovering over an image.

I don't see any headline or about attributes.